# Catching multiple errors in loop SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I have the below insert query which selects records from the `OriginalData` table where everything is of datatype `nvarchar(max)` and inserts it into the temp table which has specific column definitions i.e `MainAccount` is of type `INT`.

I am doing a row by row insert because if there is a record in `OriginalData` table where the `MainAccount` value is 'Test' the it will obviously cause a conversion error and the insert will fail. The begin try block is used to update the table with the error.

However if there are multiple errors on the same row I want to be able to capture them both and not just the first one.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [Temp] 

DECLARE @RowId INT, @MaxRowId INT  

SET @RowId = 1

SELECT @MaxRowId = MAX(RowId) 
FROM [Staging].[FactFinancialsCoded_Abbas_InitialValidationTest]

WHILE(@RowId <= @MaxRowId)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY  
    INSERT INTO [Temp] (ExtractSource, MainAccount, 
                        RecordLevel1Code, RecordLevel2Code, RecordTypeNo, 
                        TransDate, Amount, PeriodCode, CompanyCode)
        SELECT 
            ExtractSource, MainAccount,
            RecordLevel1Code, RecordLevel2Code, RecordTypeNo,
            TransDate, Amount, PeriodCode, DataAreaId
        FROM 
            [Staging].[FactFinancialsCoded_Abbas_InitialValidationTest]  
        WHERE 
            RowId = @RowId;

    PRINT @RowId;

END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  

Update [Staging].[FactFinancialsCoded_Abbas_InitialValidationTest]  
Set ValidationErrors = ERROR_MESSAGE()
where RowId = @RowId  

END CATCH 
SET @RowId += 1;      
END
```

Comment: Why are you insertong each the data row by agonising row? SQL Server's forté is working with datasets, not processing every row on it's own.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, what you're trying to do is nearly impossible. If there are multiple errors in the same row, SQL will kick the row out when it finds the _first_ one. It doesn't keep looking to see if there are more. It seems like you want your query to be a data validation application, and that's not going to work out for you.

Comment: "I am doing a row by row insert because if there is a record in OriginalData table where the MainAccount value is 'Test' the it will obviously cause a conversion error and the insert will fail. The begin try block is used to update the table with the error." Why can't you just use a `WHERE` clause: `INSERT INTO [Temp] (MainAccount, ...) select convert(int, MainAccount),... FROM [Staging].[FactFinancialsCoded_Abbas_InitialValidationTest] WHERE ISNUMERIC(MainAccount) = 1`

Comment: @Zack IsNumeric is the most poorly named function ever. So many false positives from that abomination.

Comment: You might take a look at TRY_PARSE instead of doing this row by agonizing row.

Comment: Was about to suggest using `TRY_PARSE` instead of `IS_NUMERIC`. :)

Comment: More about IsNumeric and its woes here. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/time-stop-using-isnumeric/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it this way, I handle this by using TRY_PARSE() or TRY_CONVERT() on each column that I am converting to a non-string column.

If you then need to store the validation failures in another table, you can make a second pass getting all the rows that have a non-null value in the source table and a null value in the destination table, and insert those rows into your "failed validation" table.